How to troubleshoot high "Avg CPU Load" issue?
Recently we have been facing a problem of High Avg CPU load on a centos VM monitored though Zabbix agent. The VM running MongoDB instance with 2 cores with no hyper-thereading. Zabbix captured avg load per core as >1.5 and triggering the alert.
I understand the fact that CPU load may or may not be connected with CPU Usage metric, hence I checked a few system resources like CPU Usage,I/O wait,Memory & swap usage, interrupts & switches but none of them has abnormal usage for the same period in which we facing high CPU load, in fact CPU usage was near to 0.
How reliable a spike in this metric with spike in no other metric? Is there any other metric should I look into? How can I troubleshoot this if it's a problem?
